# Suricata Error on running SC_ERR_NO_MD5_SUPPORT

Tags: rules, snort, suricata

I’m using Suricata 4.0.4,
I want to check md5 of files with this rule:

`alert http any any -> any any (msg:"FILE MD5 Check against Malware Patrol blacklist"; filemd5: /root/2018.md5.txt; sid:10203040; rev:1;)`

but after running suricata, it says:

```
<Error> - [ERRCODE: SC_ERR_NO_MD5_SUPPORT(209)] - no MD5 calculation support built in, needed for filemd5 keyword
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For me on CentOS 7.5 helped these steps:

1. Install packages (for CentOS was 'yum install ...'):

   - `nss-util`
   - `nss-util-devel`
   - `nss-devel`
   - `nspr-devel`
   - `nspr`
2. Reconfig and reinstall the Suricata whit those libs:

   - `./configure --with-libnss-libraries=/usr/lib --with-libnss-includes=/usr/include/nss/ --with-libnspr-libraries=/usr/lib --with-libnspr-includes=/usr/include/nspr`
   - `make clean`
   - `make`
   - `sudo make install-full`
3. Start Suricata: `/usr/local/bin/suricata -c /usr/local/etc/suricata/suricata.yaml -i eth0`

Also be aware not to forget keyword "**filestore;**" in your rule - without it alerts may not be catched!

Example: `alert http any any -> any any (msg:"FILE MD5 Check against Malware Patrol blacklist"; filemd5: /root/2018.md5.txt; filestore; sid:10203040; rev:1;)`